# Pandigital product sum

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> We shall say that an n-digit number is pandigital if it makes use of
>   all the digits 1 to n exactly once; for example, the 5-digit number,
>   15234, is 1 through 5 pandigital.
>
> The product 7254 is unusual, as the identity, 39 × 186 = 7254,
>   containing multiplicand, multiplier, and product is 1 through 9
>   pandigital.
>
> Find the sum of all products whose multiplicand/multiplier/product
>   identity can be written as a 1 through 9 pandigital.
>
> HINT: Some products can be obtained in more than one way so be sure to only
>   include it once in your sum.

but I'm not getting the correct answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my attempt:

```
public class Euler32 {

    public static boolean checkValue(char c,String s,int j) {    
        for(int i=j+1;i<s.length();i++)
            if(c==s.charAt(i)) 
                return true;      
        return false;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long total=0;
        long sum=0;

        for(int i1=40;i1<=999;i1++) {   
            for(int j=130;j<=9999;j++) {
                sum=i1*j;
                String s=i1+""+j+""+sum;

                if(s.length()!=9) continue;

                else {
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++) {
                        if(checkValue(s.charAt(i),s,i))
                            break;          
                        if(i+1==s.length()-1) 
                            total+=sum;      
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total sum is: "+total);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your program does not appear to correspond to problem 32.

Comment: Isn't the question saying find the sum of all the product who combination with multiplicand and multiplier having the length 9 and having the number which shouldn't be repeated. Am I correct?

Comment: NewCoder: Yeah, I think what you said.  But are the bounds of your indices too restrictive?  Just asking; I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

ok, few notes:

1. Your assumption to start from 40 is incorrect, since 4*1783=6952 is pandigital. And there is another one you are missing :)
2. You are not excluding duplicate products.

Based on the discussion with Marius, im updating the original answer, here.
This is the isPandigital method only.

```
private boolean isPandigital(int a,int b){
   int c=a*b;
   StringBuilder st =  new StringBuilder();
   st.append(a).append(b).append(c);

   if (st.length()!=9 || st.indexOf("0")>-1) return false;

   Set<Character> x=new TreeSet<Character>();

   for (int i=0;i<9; i++){
       x.add(st.charAt(i));
   }
  if (x.size()==9){
     for (int k=0;k<=cnt;k++){
        if (products[k]==c) return false;
     }
  products[++cnt]=c;
  total += c;

  return true;
  }
 return false;
}
```

I compared both codes on my machine, ten tries then average, the results are as follows:

1. Marius code: average (2070ms)
2. medopal code: average (2200ms)
3. Marius code (using String): average (4200ms)
4. medopal code (using String): average (5000ms)

I added the String vs StringBuilder comparison because apperantly it was the thing that made my original code so slow. But using StringBuilder, Marius code beats me in average 200ms only :)

Lessons learned:

- StringBuilder takes almost half the time String does. (in this experiment at least)
- When you are lazy to think, you can use ready structures. (again in this experiment at least), im not generalizing

Thanks Marius :)

Comment: Set/TreeSet is actually slower than a local well crafted for loop(instead of the function).

Comment: Its just a small quick application, the TreeSet is O(log N), I'm not sure i can do a Pandigital check in one for loop, except if I add another structure like an Array or List with IFs. So i chose the short path :), Thanks for the note anyway.

Comment: How do you add the entries to the Set? The note can be changed, just argue your point.

Comment: Its a simple isPandigital method, this is my laziest implementation.
I loop over the 9 characters string, parse and add each one to the set. for (char c:string.toCharArray()) {set.add(parse(c);} at the end return set.size()==9;

Comment: I believe you need some more, you must check for zeros. Since you already have a loop, I completely miss on your above point "I'm not sure i can do a Pandigital check in one for loop".

Comment: before the loop there is one IF, i didnt write because it wasnt the point, its checks if length==9 and str.indexOf("0")<0.

About the one "For loop", i meant i couldnt think if a simple For Loop to check if a number is pandigital. so if we use two nested for loops, i believe it would become slower than the Set. no?

Comment: Well, I doubt you have less than 2 loops this way ;) For once, indexOf needs a loop. As about the performance, it depends on how you write your nested loops. As about Set, why would you think it's faster? Have you actually tested? Would you think that just by writing more lines of code, your code will become slower?

Comment: I didnt test the performance, but while thinking quickly, i concluded that if i will use one For loop, i will need to use an Array or List to store the chars, then check at end. 
Anyway, give me just 5 minutes, i will do a nested For loop and compare with the TreeSet. will be back

Comment: ok, im back, i made two for loops, in the first loop i get the character at current index, start the nested loop from currentindex+1, and loop, if the number at current index matches any number in the nested loop then return false.

So the result is, the SET is faster, both methods are testing 10 million numbers, where there is 16 Pandigitals. The Set method takes around 5000 milli-seconds. The nested loop takes around 6500 milliseconds. If you have a better implementation dont hesitatem we are here to learn :), i just proved to myself, laziness is useful sometimes ;-)

Comment: My nested loops method only takes 1150ms(according to the profiler), I'm gonna post my code in my answer. Please also post your code with Set.

Comment: Confirming what Marius said, those two methods might seem good, but a mathematical solution will be much more faster than Brute Force.

Comment: Haha I did it using C++ (can show u the sln if you want proof) on an Intel Penryn it took around 200 msec.

Comment: i am using brute-force attack no strings no trees in C++ and also have run time 200ms ... the main idea is to create all variations of 1..9 (9! permutations) and then just make 2x(1-4 digit)+1x(the rest) numbers from it and check if a0*a1=a2 if yes (and a2 is distinct ... counted just 18 numbers)  add a2 to sum. To speed up nested loops have BYTE a[10]; where I remember which digit is used or not (the nested loops without pandigal test took ~ 36ms)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some points:

1. It is 1..9
2. Unique products
3. How comes you use 40 and 130(just curious)

(remember, understanding the problem solves 50% of it)

Recommendations:

1. Learn about `continue [label];` statement and use a local for loop instead of `checkValue`
2. Why use s.length() more than once?
3. Use `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation. There are some comments to see how I decided to choose the **lower** and the **upper limits**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/*
 * 15234, is 1 through 5 pandigital.
 * The product 7254 is unusual: 39 × 186 = 7254, containing multiplicand, multiplier, and product is 1 through 9 pandigital.
 * Find the sum of all products whose multiplicand/multiplier/product identity can be written as a 1 through 9 pandigital.
 * HINT: Some products can be obtained in more than one way so be sure to only include it once in your sum.
 */
public class P32 {
    /* Obs:
     * 1) Because x * y = y * x, let's consider x < y (avoid duplicates)
     * 2) f * abcde => at least 1 + 5 + 5 = 11 digits => too long => y <= 9876
     * 3) If x has 3 or more digits => at least 3 + 3 + 5 = 11 digits => too long
     *    x <= 98
     * 4) If y has 2 digits => at most 8 digits => y >= 123
     * 5) If x = 1 => y and product have the same value
     * */

    final private static int min = 2;
    final private static int maxOfTwoDigits = 98;
    final private static int minOfThreeDigits = 123;
    final private static int max = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Integer> goodProducts = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int multiplicand = min; multiplicand <= maxOfTwoDigits; multiplicand++) {
            for (int multiplier = minOfThreeDigits; multiplier <= max; multiplier++) {
                int product = multiplicand * multiplier;
                List<Integer> multiplicandDigits = getDigits(multiplicand);
                List<Integer> multiplierDigits = getDigits(multiplier);
                List<Integer> productDigits = getDigits(product);
                if (multiplicandDigits.size() + multiplierDigits.size()
                        + productDigits.size() == 9) {
                    productDigits.addAll(multiplierDigits);
                    productDigits.addAll(multiplicandDigits);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                        productDigits.remove((Integer) i);
                    }
                    if (productDigits.size() == 0) {
                        goodProducts.add(product);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getSum(goodProducts));
    }

    private static List<Integer> getDigits(int x) {
        List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while ( x > 0 ) {
            digits.add(x%10);
            x/=10;
        }
        return digits;
    }

    private static long getSum(Set<Integer> s) {
        long sum = 0;
        for ( Integer i : s) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

**Explanation**:

- It multiplies some numbers (that are in a specified interval) to obtain a product.
- For all 3 numbers, it gets the digits and if the total number of digits is 9, all digits are added to the same list.
- The digits 1 to 9 are then removed from the list and if the list has 0 elements, it means that the combination is pandigital.
- To avoid duplicates, the products are added to a set.

Time: **362 ms**.